# differentiate a function by other with multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ both continuos and differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I am looking for the function $h(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} (x,y)$.

How do I do this?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry for not being clear. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Alain, I found via (df/dx)*(dg/dx)^-1 and (df/dy)*(dg/dy)^-1. The results are different though. I think the solution should be a combination of those, but I am not sure and can't find on the internet.

Comment: I do not know what it means to differentiate a function with respect to another function. Can you give me a definition of what you're talking about? (Think carefully about the definition of a partial derivative before you answer me.)